# Django testing: TemplateDoesNotExist when loading fixtures. Why?

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, django-templates

I have an automatic welcome message generated from template, which is sent whenever a new user is created (through a post_save signal for the User model). Everything works as it should, except when I run manage.py test.

Django keeps complaining:

***`Problem installing fixture '.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/fixtures/context-processors-users.xml
 ...
TemplateDoesNotExist users/email_welcome.html`***

when trying to load the django.contrib.auth fixtures for testing.

Why is it so? Are the template loaders not present when loading fixtures? What could be a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why there is a problem with this template (it works for me), but probably during fixtures loading you don't want to generate this email. In this situation you can use `raw` argument wich is sent with signal. From Django docs about `raw`:

> A boolean; True if the model is saved exactly as presented (i.e. when
>   loading a fixture). One should not query/modify other records in the
>   database as the database might not be in a consistent state yet.

So your code should look like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def generate_email(sender, instance, created, raw, **kwargs):
    if not raw:
        # generate email from template
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Raw is probably the way to go. Will have to add extra separate tests for the emailing.